# how can i upgrade juju internal environment

Tags: juju, landscape, openstack-autopilot

```
ktdv1@ktdv1:~$ export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju
ktdv1@ktdv1:~$ juju status --format=tabular
[Services]       
NAME             STATUS  EXPOSED CHARM                         
haproxy          unknown false   cs:trusty/haproxy-10          
juju-gui         unknown false   cs:trusty/juju-gui-51         
landscape-server unknown false   cs:trusty/landscape-server-13 
postgresql       unknown false   cs:trusty/postgresql-27       
rabbitmq-server  unknown false   cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-26  

[Units]            
ID                 WORKLOAD-STATE AGENT-STATE VERSION MACHINE PORTS                    PUBLIC-ADDRESS MESSAGE 
haproxy/0          unknown        idle        1.25.4  0/lxc/0 80/tcp,443/tcp,10000/tcp 10.1.1.103             
juju-gui/0         unknown        idle        1.25.4  0       80/tcp,443/tcp           node1.maas             
landscape-server/0 unknown        idle        1.25.4  0/lxc/1                          10.1.1.104             
postgresql/0       unknown        idle        1.25.4  0/lxc/2 5432/tcp                 10.1.1.105             
rabbitmq-server/0  unknown        idle        1.25.4  0/lxc/3 5672/tcp                 10.1.1.106   



[Machines] 

ID         STATE   VERSION DNS        INS-ID                                                         SERIES HARDWARE                           
0          started 1.25.4  node1.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-3f9aba96-ea5d-11e5-8412-a4badb4588a6/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=73728M 

ktdv1@ktdv1:~$  **juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | 
 tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'**
Warning: Permanently added '10.1.1.151' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Warning: Permanently added '10.1.1.104' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

sudo: unable to resolve host juju-machine-0-lxc-1
sudo: unable to resolve host juju-machine-0-lxc-1
sudo: unable to resolve host juju-machine-0-lxc-1
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ **juju status --format=tabular**

[Services]            

NAME                  STATUS  EXPOSED CHARM                              
ceilometer            active  false   cs:trusty/ceilometer-16            
ceilometer-agent              false   cs:trusty/ceilometer-agent-12      
ceph                  active  false   cs:trusty/ceph-42                  
ceph-osd              unknown false   cs:trusty/ceph-osd-14              
ceph-radosgw          active  false   cs:trusty/ceph-radosgw-18          
cinder                active  false   cs:trusty/cinder-33                
glance                active  false   cs:trusty/glance-29                
keystone              active  false   cs:trusty/keystone-32              
landscape-client              false   cs:trusty/landscape-client-12      
mongodb               unknown false   cs:trusty/mongodb-28               
mysql                 active  false   cs:trusty/percona-cluster-31       
neutron-api           active  false   cs:trusty/neutron-api-22           
neutron-gateway       active  false   cs:trusty/neutron-gateway-8        
neutron-openvswitch           false   cs:trusty/neutron-openvswitch-12   
nova-cloud-controller active  false   cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-65 
nova-compute          active  false   cs:trusty/nova-compute-35          
ntp                           false   cs:trusty/ntp-12                   
ntpmaster             unknown false   cs:trusty/ntpmaster-2              
openstack-dashboard   active  false   cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-20   
rabbitmq-server       active  false   cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-42  



[Units]                 
ID                      WORKLOAD-STATE AGENT-STATE VERSION MACHINE PORTS                                   PUBLIC-ADDRESS MESSAGE                     
ceilometer/0            active         idle        1.25.3  0/lxc/1 8777/tcp                                10.1.1.113     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/8    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.113                                 
ceph-radosgw/0          active         idle        1.25.3  1/lxc/2 80/tcp                                  10.1.1.117     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/12   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.117                                 
ceph/0                  active         idle        1.25.3  0                                               node2.maas     Unit is ready and clustered 
  landscape-client/0    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node2.maas                                 
ceph/1                  active         idle        1.25.3  2                                               node4.maas     Unit is ready and clustered 
  landscape-client/5    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node4.maas                                 
ceph/2                  active         idle        1.25.3  1                                               node3.maas     Unit is ready and clustered 
  landscape-client/6    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node3.maas                                 
cinder/0                active         idle        1.25.3  2/lxc/3                                         10.1.1.121     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/15   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.121                                 
glance/0                active         idle        1.25.3  0/lxc/0 9292/tcp                                10.1.1.110     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/7    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.110                                 
keystone/0              active         idle        1.25.3  1/lxc/0                                         10.1.1.111     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/13   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.111                                 
mongodb/0               unknown        idle        1.25.3  2/lxc/0 27017/tcp,27019/tcp,27021/tcp,28017/tcp 10.1.1.112                                 
  landscape-client/9    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.112                                 
mysql/0                 active         idle        1.25.3  0/lxc/2                                         10.1.1.116     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/10   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.116                                 
neutron-api/0           active         idle        1.25.3  1/lxc/3 9696/tcp                                10.1.1.120     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/14   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.120                                 
neutron-gateway/0       active         idle        1.25.3  0                                               node2.maas     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/1    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node2.maas                                 
  ntp/0                 unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node2.maas                                 
nova-cloud-controller/0 active         idle        1.25.3  2/lxc/2 3333/tcp,8773/tcp,8774/tcp,9696/tcp     10.1.1.118     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/16   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.118                                 
nova-compute/0          active         idle        1.25.3  2                                               node4.maas     Unit is ready               
  ceilometer-agent/0    active         idle        1.25.3                                                  node4.maas     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/3    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node4.maas                                 
  neutron-openvswitch/0 active         idle        1.25.3                                                  node4.maas     Unit is ready               
  ntp/1                 unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node4.maas                                 
nova-compute/1          active         idle        1.25.3  1                                               node3.maas     Unit is ready               
  ceilometer-agent/1    active         idle        1.25.3                                                  node3.maas     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/4    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node3.maas                                 
  neutron-openvswitch/1 active         idle        1.25.3                                                  node3.maas     Unit is ready               
  ntp/2                 unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  node3.maas                                 
ntpmaster/0             unknown        idle        1.25.3  0/lxc/3 123/udp                                 10.1.1.119                                 
  landscape-client/2    unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.119                                 
openstack-dashboard/0   active         idle        1.25.3  1/lxc/1 80/tcp,443/tcp                          10.1.1.114     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/17   unknown        idle        1.25.3                                                  10.1.1.114                                 
rabbitmq-server/0       active         idle        1.25.3  2/lxc/1 5672/tcp                                10.1.1.115     Unit is ready               
  landscape-client/11   unknown        idle        1.25.3  

                                            10.1.1.115                                 

[Machines] 

ID         STATE   VERSION DNS        INS-ID                                                         SERIES HARDWARE                           
0          started 1.25.3  node2.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-1f8f08b2-ea60-11e5-9b6f-a4badb4588a6/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=73728M 
1          started 1.25.3  node3.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-b610fbce-ea60-11e5-a33e-a4badb4588a6/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=73728M 
2          started 1.25.3  node4.maas /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-be5b9fa6-eabe-11e5-a33e-a4badb4588a6/ trusty arch=amd64 cpu-cores=16 mem=73728M 

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ juju deploy --to 0 juju-gui

ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up

landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$ **juju status juju-gui**

environment: "1"
machines: {}
services: {}
networks:
  subnet-1:
    provider-id: subnet-1
    cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
  subnet-2:
    provider-id: subnet-2
    cidr: 10.1.1.0/24
landscape@juju-machine-0-lxc-1:~$
```

How can I upgrade Juju's internal environment from 1.25.3 to 1.25.4 ?

I was able to upgrade the external environment by using the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/proposed
juju upgrade-juju --version 1.25.4 —debug
```

Please advise: how can I accomplish the same on the internal Juju environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can update Juju internal environment by following steps

```
juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1 sudo -u landscape -E bash'
juju set-env agent-stream=proposed
```

To upgrade specific version for example 1.25.4

```
juju upgrade-juju --version 1.25.4 --debug
```

To Upgrade next version from 1.25.3 to 1.25.3.1

```
juju upgrade-juju --upload-tools
```

Hope this will help.